# How to resolve system directories paths independently of system locale?

Tags: node.js, linux, windows, powershell, shell

### TLDR

I need to get paths to system directories like "Screenshots":

On an English system. I can just use this one:

`C:/Users/User/Pictures/Screenshots`

How do I get the path to "Screenshots" directory on a non-English system?

`C:/Users/User/Pictures/[NAME]`

### Description

I have a [file manager app](https://github.com/aleksey-hoffman/sigma-file-manager), it displays system directories and loads them on click.

The app can run system commands via Powershell and use Node.js (preferred)

### Problem

The problem is, it only works if the system has English system language.

Currently, to resolve the "Screenshots" directory path, the app simply joins the User directory with the word "Screenshots"

```js
const pictures = electronRemote.app.getPath('pictures')
const screenshots = PATH.join(pictures, 'Screenshots')
```

[link to the line in code](https://github.com/aleksey-hoffman/sigma-file-manager/blob/08d4dcef171cafce26c3a6d5dacad92920890154/src/appPaths.js#L25)

Expectedly, the `C:/Users/User/Screenshots` path only exists on English systems.

One way to solve this is to use short names, at least on Windows, I know that system directories have short names like `SCREEN~1` and `WALLPA~1` for Screenshots and Wallpapers directories, but if I use these names the paths will look like this:

`C:/Users/User/SCREEN~1` instead of `C:/Users/User/Screenshots` throughout the app.

And even if I were to run these paths through a function to convert it to readable name, how would I know which word to replace it with? I need to get the name in the system's language.

Are these translations stored somewhere on the system? Can I just retrieve the translated directory name and use that in the code above?

### Question

- How do I make it to get / resolve the actual path of system directories like Screenshots and Wallpapers, independently of system locale?
- If you know how to do it, could you please suggest the solution for all platforms (Win, Mac, Linux)?

Should I just use the short names like `SCREEN~1` and then automatically replace all the occurrences in UI and also filter all paths through a function that replaces this short name with the actual path throughout the whole app? Seems like a lot of work, this approach

Comment: Check out an [enum](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.environment.specialfolder?view=net-5.0) for special folders.

Comment: Windows PowerShell `[System.Enum]::GetNames( [System.Environment+SpecialFolder]) |ForEach-Object {$_; [Environment]::GetFolderPath( [Environment+SpecialFolder]::$_)}`

Comment: Thank you guys. @JosefZ how do you convert that output to JSON? I tried adding `| ConvertTo-json` at the end but the entries are not corelated as key / value pairs

Comment: It doesn't seem to list the Screenshots and Wallpapers directories though

Comment: `[System.Enum]::GetNames( [System.Environment+SpecialFolder])|
ForEach-Object { [pscustomobject]@{$_ = [Environment]::GetFolderPath( [Environment+SpecialFolder]::$_)}}|
ConvertTo-Json`

Comment: Or `[System.Enum]::GetNames( [System.Environment+SpecialFolder])| ForEach-Object { [pscustomobject]@{SpecFolder=$_; Path = [Environment]::GetFolderPath( [Environment+SpecialFolder]::$_)}}`